# CiviVolunteer Stopped Working with upgrade to 4.7.29

Tags: civivolunteer

I upgraded CiviCRM from 4.7.28 to 4.7.29. CiviVolunteer is at 4.7.21-2.2.3. I have active projects but the "Manage Volunteer Projects" screen comes up blank. The "Search for Volunteer Opportunities" reports "No results found".

I can create a new project, but it also doesn't show up. I see the projects in the database (civicrm_volunteer_project), although I noticed the new project I tried to create is listed in three identical records.

I have Angular Profiles 4.6-1.0.2 and am on WordPress 4.9.1.

I tried "cv flush" as described in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21210.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this was the problem, but the default PHP interpreter was at 7.1. I noticed CiviEvent was also not working (error message about "pass by reference"). I set PHP back to 5.6 and both CiviEvent and CiviVolunteer seem to be working.

The CiviCRM status screen is giving notice "PHP Out-of-Date: This system uses PHP version 5.6.32. This meets the minimum recommendations and you do not need to upgrade immediately, but the preferred version is 7.0."

Update July 3 2018: Currently at CiviCRM 5.2.2 with CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1 and was able to move to PHP 7.1.18 with no issues.